# "to repose upon": is it correct?

Tags: idioms

I was wondering whether using "to repose upon" as in the below example from The Free Dictionary is correct (its definition: "*2. To be based on, exist in, or take support from something.*"). I haven't found any instances of its modern usage with this meaning. Is it a correct alternative to saying "to be based on", even if a bit pedantic or archaic? Cheers.

> For me, faith must **repose upon** reason, logic, and evidence.

https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/repose+upon

Comment: I would say it is archaic, except perhaps in theology. The iWeb corpus has 25 instances of _repose upon_, of which I think eight are literal (repose upon a couch or a cushion), and most of the rest are religious. (A number are _repose upon the bosom of ..._ - one of these is talking about a literal bosom, and the rest are theological).

Comment: @ColinFine 'reposes **on**' has a fairly large number of Google hits, many quite recent, so I think 'upon' may account for a lot of the 'archaic' feel of the expression. Still quite formal though.

Comment: Good point, @MichaelHarvey. When I run the same search on iWeb with _repose on_ (and limiting _repose_ to be a verb) I get 75 hits. The majority are still either literal, or in a religious context; but there are a few like the OP's example.

Comment: Also, that's one of the worst understandings of what faith is. Poor choice for a dictionary